# game programming iphone osx android 1.6 shared codebase

Tags: iphone, android

im planning to develop a game for iphone and android. what programming language can i use to create a shared codebase between the two platform. i understand that there are some parts which are device specific.

Answer (score 5):

The shared part should be in C or C++, since the new iPhone SDK agreement doesn't allow non-C languages (and Android allows C and C++ code through the [Native Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)).  The platform-specific parts should be in Objective-C for the iPhone and I'm guessing Java for Android (I haven't done Android programming).